# Scala try-catch not catching exception

Tags: scala, try-catch

As far as I understand, the following code snippet should execute fine. `Stream("A", "").toIterable.map(_.head)` throws an exception, which should be caught by the `try` block.

```
import org.scalatest.FunSuite

class TryCatchTest extends FunSuite {
  test("Try failure") {
    List(1).flatMap {
      _ =>
        try {
          Stream("A", "").toIterable.map(_.head)
        } catch {
          case e: Throwable => Nil
        }
    }
  }
}
```

But when I run it, it crashes with the following error:

```
next on empty iterator
java.util.NoSuchElementException: next on empty iterator
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$2.next(Iterator.scala:39)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$2.next(Iterator.scala:37)
    at scala.collection.IndexedSeqLike$Elements.next(IndexedSeqLike.scala:63)
    at scala.collection.IterableLike$class.head(IterableLike.scala:107)
    at scala.collection.immutable.StringOps.scala$collection$IndexedSeqOptimized$$super$head(StringOps.scala:30)
    at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.head(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:126)
    at scala.collection.immutable.StringOps.head(StringOps.scala:30)
    at TryCatchTest$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(TryCatchTest.scala:8)
    at TryCatchTest$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(TryCatchTest.scala:8)
    at scala.collection.immutable.Stream$$anonfun$map$1.apply(Stream.scala:418)
    at scala.collection.immutable.Stream$$anonfun$map$1.apply(Stream.scala:418)
    at scala.collection.immutable.Stream$Cons.tail(Stream.scala:1222)
    at scala.collection.immutable.Stream$Cons.tail(Stream.scala:1212)
    at scala.collection.immutable.Stream.foreach(Stream.scala:595)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.flatMap(List.scala:327)
    at TryCatchTest$$anonfun$1.apply$mcV$sp(TryCatchTest.scala:5)
    at TryCatchTest$$anonfun$1.apply(TryCatchTest.scala:5)
    at TryCatchTest$$anonfun$1.apply(TryCatchTest.scala:5)
    at org.scalatest.Transformer$$anonfun$apply$1.apply$mcV$sp(Transformer.scala:22)
    at org.scalatest.OutcomeOf$class.outcomeOf(OutcomeOf.scala:85)
    at org.scalatest.OutcomeOf$.outcomeOf(OutcomeOf.scala:104)
    at org.scalatest.Transformer.apply(Transformer.scala:22)
    at org.scalatest.Transformer.apply(Transformer.scala:20)
    at org.scalatest.FunSuiteLike$$anon$1.apply(FunSuiteLike.scala:166)
    at org.scalatest.Suite$class.withFixture(Suite.scala:1122)
    at org.scalatest.FunSuite.withFixture(FunSuite.scala:1555)
    at org.scalatest.FunSuiteLike$class.invokeWithFixture$1(FunSuiteLike.scala:163)
    at org.scalatest.FunSuiteLike$$anonfun$runTest$1.apply(FunSuiteLike.scala:175)
    at org.scalatest.FunSuiteLike$$anonfun$runTest$1.apply(FunSuiteLike.scala:175)
    at org.scalatest.SuperEngine.runTestImpl(Engine.scala:306)
    at org.scalatest.FunSuiteLike$class.runTest(FunSuiteLike.scala:175)
    at org.scalatest.FunSuite.runTest(FunSuite.scala:1555)
    at org.scalatest.FunSuiteLike$$anonfun$runTests$1.apply(FunSuiteLike.scala:208)
    at org.scalatest.FunSuiteLike$$anonfun$runTests$1.apply(FunSuiteLike.scala:208)
    at org.scalatest.SuperEngine$$anonfun$traverseSubNodes$1$1.apply(Engine.scala:413)
    at org.scalatest.SuperEngine$$anonfun$traverseSubNodes$1$1.apply(Engine.scala:401)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)
    at org.scalatest.SuperEngine.traverseSubNodes$1(Engine.scala:401)
    at org.scalatest.SuperEngine.org$scalatest$SuperEngine$$runTestsInBranch(Engine.scala:396)
    at org.scalatest.SuperEngine.runTestsImpl(Engine.scala:483)
    at org.scalatest.FunSuiteLike$class.runTests(FunSuiteLike.scala:208)
    at org.scalatest.FunSuite.runTests(FunSuite.scala:1555)
    at org.scalatest.Suite$class.run(Suite.scala:1424)
    at org.scalatest.FunSuite.org$scalatest$FunSuiteLike$$super$run(FunSuite.scala:1555)
    at org.scalatest.FunSuiteLike$$anonfun$run$1.apply(FunSuiteLike.scala:212)
    at org.scalatest.FunSuiteLike$$anonfun$run$1.apply(FunSuiteLike.scala:212)
    at org.scalatest.SuperEngine.runImpl(Engine.scala:545)
    at org.scalatest.FunSuiteLike$class.run(FunSuiteLike.scala:212)
    at org.scalatest.FunSuite.run(FunSuite.scala:1555)
    at org.scalatest.tools.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.scala:55)
    at org.scalatest.tools.Runner$$anonfun$doRunRunRunDaDoRunRun$3.apply(Runner.scala:2563)
    at org.scalatest.tools.Runner$$anonfun$doRunRunRunDaDoRunRun$3.apply(Runner.scala:2557)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)
    at org.scalatest.tools.Runner$.doRunRunRunDaDoRunRun(Runner.scala:2557)
    at org.scalatest.tools.Runner$$anonfun$runOptionallyWithPassFailReporter$2.apply(Runner.scala:1044)
    at org.scalatest.tools.Runner$$anonfun$runOptionallyWithPassFailReporter$2.apply(Runner.scala:1043)
    at org.scalatest.tools.Runner$.withClassLoaderAndDispatchReporter(Runner.scala:2722)
    at org.scalatest.tools.Runner$.runOptionallyWithPassFailReporter(Runner.scala:1043)
    at org.scalatest.tools.Runner$.run(Runner.scala:883)
    at org.scalatest.tools.Runner.run(Runner.scala)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.scala.testingSupport.scalaTest.ScalaTestRunner.runScalaTest2(ScalaTestRunner.java:138)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.scala.testingSupport.scalaTest.ScalaTestRunner.main(ScalaTestRunner.java:28)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:140)
```

What is interesting, is that it will behave as expected if I make any of the following changes:

- replace `flatMap` with `map`
- replace `"A"` with `""`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is delayed evaluation from `Stream`/`Iterable`. This is very easy to see if you break it up into smaller pieces.

```
scala> Stream("A", "").toIterable.map(_.head)
res7: Iterable[Char] = Stream(A, ?)
```

Mapping the `Stream` to `_.head` means we're going to treat the strings as collections, and the empty string as a collection has no `head`, so it will throw an exception. But it doesn't throw an exception right away, because an `Iterable` is still lazy like `Stream`, as you can see above. Only the first element as evaluated. If we make it non-lazy, it throws the exception:

```
scala> Stream("A", "").toIterable.map(_.head)
java.util.NoSuchElementException: next on empty iterator
```

Or, if you replace the `"A"` with `""`, you will also get an exception, because the head of the `Stream` is evaluated and mapped to `head`, which has none.

```
scala> Stream("", "").toIterable.map(_.head).toList
java.util.NoSuchElementException: next on empty iterator
```

The only exception that will be caught in your code is when the `head` of the `Stream` or `Iterable` throws it. Okay, so then why does `map` not throw the exception, but `flatMap` does? Well, this `map` doesn't actually do anything to the `Stream`:

```
scala> List(1).map { _ => Stream("A", "").toIterable.map(_.head) }
res11: List[Iterable[Char]] = List(Stream(A, ?))
```

So it is left untouched, with unevaluated members. But `flatMap` will try to flatten the `Iterable`s into one collection, so they must be evaluated to make a new collection. And in doing so, the exception is thrown:

```
scala> List(1).flatMap { _ => Stream("A", "").toIterable.map(_.head) }
java.util.NoSuchElementException: next on empty iterator
```

Comment: Thanks for the breakdown. I'm not sure I understand why the `try-catch` gets stripped, though. EDIT: Scratch that, just got it. Thanks!

Comment: @KaarelNummert Because the `Iterable` is successfully created. The `try`/`catch` isn't going to follow that `Iterable` around, waiting for it to throw an exception. The problem is what you do with the `Iterable` afterward.